# Get first value of translate3d with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm trying to get the first value of `translat3d` from a style attribute.
In the real app the `.css('transform')` wont work so thats why I'm using `attr.('style'...)`

Can someone explain how to get the first value of the translate3d?

http://jsfiddle.net/6gLqw4df/2/

Comment: Why not use something like `var slideTransform = $('#mySlide').css('transform');` which would return the matrix of the 3D effect?

Comment: Because its a slider that opens after I click a link and css('transform') returns wrong results

Comment: could you provide a demo for this? I just feel that the "3D" part of the transform isn't actually required here (are you just looking to move the div horizontally?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tricky but it works. To be more obvious, I increase 100px per one click.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var slideTransform = $('#mySlide').attr('style').split(';');
    slideTransform = $.map(slideTransform, function(style){
        style = style.trim();
        if (style.startsWith('transform:translate3d')) {
            var match = style.match(/transform:translate3d\((.+)px,(.+)px,(.+)px\)/);
            var value = parseInt(match[1]);
            var newValue = value + 100;
            console.log(newValue);
            return 'transform:translate3d(' + newValue + 'px, 0px, 0px)';
        }
        return style;
    });
    // add 100px to first value of translate3d
    $('#mySlide').attr('style', slideTransform.join(';'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5rhyug/

Sorry for my ugly code. `startsWith` can be removed by inspecting on `match` result. (like checking its length, etc.)